# How to get value in SimpleXMLElement object?

Tags: php

This (var_dump) is a XMLElement object  of Alexa rank of a website. All I want is to read the RANK value( which is 4 here). How to get it?
I'm trying to do:

**print (string) $xml->SD->REACH->RANK;** //but not working out

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#1 (4) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["VER"]=>
    string(3) "0.9"
    ["URL"]=>
    string(10) "yahoo.com/"
    ["HOME"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["AID"]=>
    string(1) "="
  }
  ["KEYWORDS"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
    ["KEYWORD"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#12 (1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["VAL"]=>
          string(10) "On the Web"
        }
      }
      [1]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (1) {
        ["@attributes"]=>
        array(1) {
          ["VAL"]=>
          string(11) "Web Portals"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["DMOZ"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#14 (1) {
    ["SITE"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 (2) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["BASE"]=>
        string(10) "yahoo.com/"
        ["TITLE"]=>
        string(6) "Yahoo!"
        ["DESC"]=>
        string(133) "A major internet portal and service provider offering search results, customizable content, chatrooms, free e-mail, clubs, and pager."
      }
      ["CATS"]=>
      object(SimpleXMLElement)#8 (1) {
        ["CAT"]=>
        array(3) {
          [0]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#11 (1) {
            ["@attributes"]=>
            array(3) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(45) "Top/Computers/Internet/On_the_Web/Web_Portals"
              ["TITLE"]=>
              string(22) "On the Web/Web Portals"
              ["CID"]=>
              string(6) "375197"
            }
          }
          [1]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#10 (1) {
            ["@attributes"]=>
            array(3) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(34) "Top/Computers/Companies/Yahoo_Inc."
              ["TITLE"]=>
              string(20) "Companies/Yahoo Inc."
              ["CID"]=>
              string(6) "376283"
            }
          }
          [2]=>
          object(SimpleXMLElement)#9 (1) {
            ["@attributes"]=>
            array(3) {
              ["ID"]=>
              string(118) "Top/Regional/North_America/United_States/California/Localities/S/Sunnyvale/Business_and_Economy/Computers_and_Internet"
              ["TITLE"]=>
              string(43) "Business and Economy/Computers and Internet"
              ["CID"]=>
              string(6) "627776"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  ["SD"]=>
  object(SimpleXMLElement)#13 (3) {
    ["POPULARITY"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["URL"]=>
        string(10) "yahoo.com/"
        ["TEXT"]=>
        string(1) "4"
      }
    }
    ["REACH"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["RANK"]=>
        string(1) "4"
      }
    }
    ["RANK"]=>
    object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) {
      ["@attributes"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["DELTA"]=>
        string(2) "+0"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's an attribute of a DOM node. Have a look at [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) how to access descendants and attribute nodes.

Comment: @Felix Kling I'm able to get it like this: $xml->SD->REACH["RANK"]

Answer (score 1):

I found this in the docs:

```
$XML =
'<data>
   <USERS>
      <ID>alang</ID>
      <NAME>Alan Gruskoff</NAME>
      <ROLE>mgr</ROLE>
   </USERS>
</data>';

$xmlObject = new SimpleXMLElement($XML);

$node = $xmlObject->children();

echo  $node[0]->ID;
echo  $node[0]->NAME;
echo  $node[0]->ROLE;
```

======

I would imagine you would need to loop through the `children()` of the node and then `$node->getName()` to see if its the one you are looking for.

Hope this helps.